# Device reachable but not pingable

Tags: networking, ping, dlna

In a domestic LAN I have a TV connected to a router via copper straight cable and a PC connected wirelessly.

I stream stuff to the TV from the PC using DLNA. So the TV is somehow known to the PC, it has an ARP entry and all.

But when I ping the IP address of the TV from the PC I get 100% lost.

Everything works well, I'm just curious, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all devices respond to pings. It's not required by any protocol. In fact, pings use a separate protocol from normal traffic. When you're connecting to your device and using it, you're almost certainly using either TCP or UDP, but pinging uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), specifically, control messages 8 (echo request) and 0 (echo reply). ICMP isn't built on any [Layer 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) protocol.

Since your network's [Layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) protocol is Ethernet/MAC, everything to which you can deliver packets must respond to ARP queries. Again, though, there's no obligation that those devices care about ICMP, which is at a different layer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that ICMP is disabled on your PC. You can [enable it](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6?auth=1) from your PC.

Comment: PC ping other devices in the LAN, and it replies to pings from other devices.